# proper syntax for splitting large mp3 files into several

Tags: regex, linux, audio, mp3, ubuntu-16.04

I can split one large mp3 file into several files based on silence using the mp3split command / program below

```
mp3splt -f -t 4.0 -a -d split audio_file.mp3
```

and I get

```
split/audio_file_000m_00s_005m_00s.mp3
```

but how can I get

```
split/000m_00s_005m_00s_audio_file.mp3
```

or increment by one in the front

```
split/000_audio_file_000m_00s_005m_00s.mp3
split/001_audio_file_005m_00s_010m_00s.mp3
```

I looked at the syntax http://wiki.librivox.org/index.php/How_To_Split_With_Mp3Splt but couldn't figure out what needs to change in my syntax.

**I'm using ubuntu 16.04 64bit linux**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `-o` (output format) option.

Try something like:

```
mp3splt -o @N3_@f -f -t 4.0 -a -d split audio_file.mp3
```

Giving you:

```
001_audio_file.mp3, 
002_audio_file.mp3, 
003_audio_file.mp3…
```

The [man page](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/documentation/man.html) is a little messy, but it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
mp3splt -o @N3_@mm_@ss_@f -f -t 4.0 -a -d split audio_file.mp3
```

which gives me

```
/split/001_000m_00s_audio_file.mp3
/split/002_004m_00s_audio_file.mp3
```